# Is it possible to remove different array index in foreach loop or for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Few questions to be answered here,

1>When we start a foreach loop does the object inside the foreach loop goes into local scope?

```
foreach($brands as $k=>$b)
        { 


        }
```

So in the above example when we loop through $brands does it store $brands in local scope and iterate through it such that if there is a change in different $brand index eg: $brand[10] then it throws an error?

2> I am trying to achieve the following solution

```
foreach($brands as $k=>$b)
        { 
           foreach($brands as $key=>$value)
           { 
              if(statement is true)
              {
                unset($brands[$key]);
              }

           }

        }
```

Similar to question number 1. when I do a foreach loop and delete a index in another foreach loop, will the first foreach loop look or will there still be that deleted index in the first foreach loop? Or will the first foreach loop iterate through each brand and delete the index such that it will not iterate it if the index is deleted in the inner loop. Therefore, I would like to know how this foreach loop works and would like to know if it stores the index value first and iterates through it or will the foreach loop looks for any change in the index inside its local scope.

Comment: It will delete the index and continue to iterate the current data of brands without the deleted index

Comment: You need to use address `&` to modify the key of the original instance

Comment: is it possible to make changes in the iteration during iteration?,

Comment: @Thamilan , does the reference works in php like it does in c++?

Comment: I wonder why you don’t just try this and see what happens? BTW: I would prefer to modify the value by using the `key` (`$brands[$key] = ...`) instead of using `&`.

Comment: Do not ask two questions at the same time, you can ask them as two separate questions.

Comment: dear friend its not two questions. its the same question.

Comment: the first question is related to the second question in different scope which has same answer

Answer (score 0):

> 1> When we start a foreach loop does the object inside the foreach loop goes into local scope?

PHP provides only two types of [variable scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php): the global scope and the function scope.

All variables that are set outside any function are global variables; they belong to the global scope and can be used only outside the functions.

All variables set inside a function are local variables; they can be used only inside the body of that particular function.

There is no block-level scope. Every variable you use inside any block-level statement (`foreach`, `for`, `while`, `if` etc.) belongs to the scope of the code that contains the block (global or local to a function).

> 2> I am trying to achieve the following solution
>
> ```
>    foreach($brands as $k=>$b)
>    { 
>       foreach($brands as $key=>$value)
>       { 
>          if(statement is true)
>          {
>            unset($brands[$key]);
>          }
>       }
>    }
> ```

Adding or removing elements from an array while enumerating its values is not safe. Maybe it works (I didn't test it) but the behaviour can change on a different PHP version.

If you need to enumerate the array values and remove some of them you better copy the items you want to keep into a new array:

```
// create a temporary array
$copy = array();
// copy the values we need
foreach ($brands as $key => $value) {
    if (statement is false) {
        $copy[$key] = $value;
    }
}
// replace the original with the temporary
$brands = $copy;
// we don't need $copy any more
unset($copy);
```

Or, even better, use the PHP function [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$brands = array_filter(
    $brands,
    function ($item) {
        if (should keep $item) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
);
```

It iterates over the array elements and passes each of them to the provided callback function. If the function returns `TRUE` then it copies the element in the returned array, otherwise it ignores it.

If you need to use the associated keys to decide if an element must be kept or  removed then you can pass `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` as the third argument to [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). In this case it passes both the value and the key as arguments to the callback function:

```
$brands = array_filter(
    $brands,
    function ($value, $key) {
        if (should keep $value) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> When we start a foreach loop does the object inside the foreach loop goes into local scope?

No. to your first question. Php has no block-level scoping. your two loops will be working on exact copy of your array `$brands`. your variables inherit the immediate available scope, so if you called your above code in a function, they will have function scope or global scope otherwise.

> when I do a foreach loop and delete a index in another foreach loop, will the first foreach loop look or will there still be that deleted index in the first foreach loop?

Yes. Because your loops are working on the same variable, any changes you make in foreach block will be reflected in other. This is possible because loops don't run cocurrently but one loop runs modifying internal array pointers as it steps through elements and when it leaves the loop block, it resets the internal pointers effectively restoring the variable for use by other code

Answer (score 0):

It may not be very convenient for others, but what I did next worked for me.

I cloned brands table into two:
$brands = $brans2

then:

```
foreach($brands as $k=>$b)
{ 
      foreach($brands2 as $key=>$value)
      { 
        if(statement is true)
       {
         unset($brands2[$key]);
       }
    }
unset($brands[$k]);
}
```